# Python write operation not writing quickly enough

Tags: python, selenium, oop, web-scraping

I don't know why this started happening recently. I have a function that opens a new text file, writes a url to it, then closes it, but it is not made immediately after the `f.close()` is executed. The problem is that a function after it `open_url()` needs to read from that text file a url, but since nothing is there, my program errors out.

Ironically, after my program errors out and I stop it, the url.txt file is made haha. Anyone know why this is happening with the python `.write()` action? Is there another way to create a text file and write a line of text to that text file faster?

```
    @staticmethod
    def write_url():
        if not path.exists('url.txt'):
            url = UrlObj().url
            print(url)
            with open('url.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write(url)
                f.close
        else:
            pass



    @staticmethod
    def open_url():
        x = open('url.txt', 'r')
        y = x.read()
        return y



def main():

    scraper = Job()
    scraper.write_url()
    url = scraper.open_url()
    results = scraper.load_craigslist_url(url)
    scraper.kill()
    dictionary_of_listings = scraper.organizeResults(results)
    scraper.to_csv(dictionary_of_listings)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()

    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(main, 'interval', hours=1)
    scheduler.start()
```

There is another class called url that prompts the user to add attributes to a bare url for seleenium to use. `UrlObj().url` gives you the url to write which is used to write to the new text file. If the url.txt file already exists, then pass and go to open_url()and get the url from the url.txt file to pass to the url variable which is used to start the scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a work around. If the file does not exist then return the url to be fed directly to load_craigslist_url. If the text file exists then just read from the text file.